# How do you stop iPhoto/Aperture launching when you sync an iPad?

Tags: ipad, photos.app, aperture

How do you stop iPhoto/Aperture launching when you sync an iPad?

Comment: FWIW, I've never had iPhoto launch when I sync my iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Image Capture, connect the iPad, select it when it appears in the list on the left.  On the lower left will be a selector for what app to open when it connects, you can pick None.

Comment: I knew this from previous OS versions but when I searched for Image Capture I couldn't find it so I assumed it had been removed. I searched for "imagecapture" :(

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/4183/how-to-prevent-iphoto-09-from-opening-when-camera-is-connected/

These are the directions for blocking iPhoto.